# Google Cloud storage - delete processed files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

Can you please help me here:

I'm batch processing files (json files) from Cloud Storage to write the data into BigQuery.

I have a topic created with a Cloud Function(to process the message and write the data into BQ) subscriber to the topic.

I have created a 'DataFlow' job to notify the topic for any json files created/stored in my source bucket.

The above flow processes the json file and inserts rows in to BQ table perfectly.

I want to delete the source json file from the Cloud Storage after the file is successfully processed. Any input on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Client Libraries and then make a call to the objects delete function at some point in your pipeline.

First install the the [Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) for example and after the file is processed make a call to the delete method as shown in this [sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-java):

```
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
boolean deleted = storage.delete(blobId);
if (deleted) {
  // the blob was deleted
} else {
  // the blob was not found
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Another thing that comes to mind is to use [Pub/Sub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#overview) in order to know when certain events occur in your storage bucket. But so far the list of [supported events](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#events) doesn't include object creation:

> **OBJECT_FINALIZE**   Sent when a new object (or a new generation of an existing object) is successfully created in the bucket ...
>
> **OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE**    Sent when the metadata of an existing object changes ...
>
> **OBJECT_DELETE** Sent when an object has been permanently deleted. This includes objects that are overwritten or are deleted as part of
> the bucket's lifecycle configuration ...
>
> **OBJECT_ARCHIVE**    Only sent when a bucket has enabled object versioning ...
>
> **Important**: Additional event types may be released later. Client code
> should either safely ignore unrecognized event types, or else
> explicitly specify in their notification configuration which event
> types they are prepared to accept.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply Victor.

Comment: The problem I have is that in the Pub/Sub message that is forwarded to the 'Cloud Function' I dont have the name of the object that needs to be deleted.